# MPI - non-contiguous memory block in one-sided communication

Tags: c++, mpi

I'm wondering if there is a way to create a window on a non-contiguous memory block. 
For example :

```
process 0 should fill first 20 elements, third 20 elements and so on
process 1 should fill second 20 elements, fourth 20 elements and so on
in memory of process 2 for example.
```

I want to achieve this exactly with one-sided communication. Am I right that the only way is to declare many windows?

UPD: one more question: can MPI window be created in async mode?

Comment: This could be achieved by creating appropriate datatypes with holes and using those as target datatype in `MPI_Put`.

Comment: How about this paper [Exploiting transparent remote memory access for non-contiguous- and one-sided-communication](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1016562/)

Comment: @arash, thank you, really useful paper.